# Why my text appears like this?

Tags: php, text, ckeditor

In my addpost form i put my text in paragraphs like this:

> Morbitincidunt maurisque eros molest nunc anteget sed vel lacus mus semper.
>
> Anterdumnullam interdum eros dui urna consequam ac nisl nullam ligula vestassa.
>
> Condimentumfelis et amet tellent quisquet a leo lacus nec augue accumsan sagittislaorem dolor sum at urna.

But on my website its appears like this:

> Morbitincidunt maurisque eros molest nunc anteget sed vel lacus mus semper. Anterdumnullam interdum eros dui urna consequam ac nisl nullam ligula vestassa. Condimentumfelis et amet tellent quisquet a leo lacus nec augue accumsan sagittislaorem dolor sum at urna.

Someone knows how to fix this problem ? I use "ckeditor" in my "addposts" form.
In the table of my DB the text appears like in the 1st example wich i gave. Only the problem is how it's appears in my website.

Comment: Use [nl2br()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to convert standard new line characters to HTML line break characters when you display the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The simplest way is to use `nl2br()`.
2. If you don't want to use `<br/>`, and if you want to use `<p></p>` tags, you can use this function:

   ```
    function convert ($text) {
      $text = trim($text);
      return '<p>' . preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '</p><p>', $text) . '</p>';
    }
   ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try allow **br** element in config:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'p br';
```

or replace br tag when pasting text:

```
editor.on( 'paste', function( evt ) {
        var data = evt.data.dataValue;
        data = data.replace( /<br \/>|<br>|<br\/>/g, '</p><p>' );
        evt.data.dataValue = data;
    });
```

bun only if `config.enterMode` was **NOT** changed to `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;`